# How do I specify celery app location in the celery -A argument?

Tags: celery

I have an app.py with a celery definition located in /foo/app.py.

/foo/app.py

```
from agent import create_app, ext_celery

app = create_app()
celery = ext_celery.celery

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If I cd into /foo and run `celery -A app.celery worker` everything starts as expected.

If I am somewhere else, like ~, the following fails `celery -A /foo/app.celery worker`

How do I give a path to the celery -A argument?

I am trying to specify celery as a service, but it fails because it is not being run in the project folder.

Comment: i found a similar issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171010/why-i-cant-start-celery-with-a-path-to-an-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use $PYTHONPATH . Something like `PYTHONPATH=/foo celery -A app.celery worker` should work.

Or alternatively:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/foo
celery -A app.celery worker
```